# Pass array as a parameter (use Clone() or use the reference)?

Tags: c#, class

I'm currently refactoring my code and found a few things I never was happy with. I'm, dealing with a large amount of large arrays and I don't want to copy the arrays all the time. Currently my code look like following:

```
public class Mtx
{
    float[] Data;

    public Mtx(float[] data_in)
    {
        Data = (float[])data_in.Clone();
    }
}
```

because otherwise, if I simply do this

```
public class Mtx
{
    float[] Data;

    public Mtx(float[] data_in)
    {
        Data = data_in;
    }
}
```

Changing the data_in input argument would also change the field itself. Is there a global solution to this. How do you solve this?

Thanks

Comment: FYI - In the code supplied, `Data` is a **field** and not a **property**.

Comment: "How do you solve this?" - by not depending on arrays so much...

Comment: @Greg. Does it matter if its a field or a property here?

Comment: @Henk: What if I need the arrays? All my data is in arrays. These are images and volumes. I see no way around.

Comment: @msedi - Using a property vs a field wouldn't affect the behavior of your example code. However, accuracy of communication is important. This is a technical field and proper use of terminology will reduce the potential for confusion. It's not a big deal in this case - I just wanted you to be aware of the correct term.

Comment: @msedi: If you need big arrays than make sure you minimize copying.

Comment: @Greg. Understood ;-) You are right. It's a field.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if your intent is to provide read-only access to the array and to prevent consumers of Mtx from modifying the incoming array, you could use the [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) class.  Though it might take some refactoring to be passing around these collections as instantiating a new one in Mtx's constructor (I believe) would essentially copy the data into the ReadOnlyCollection repeating the work done in your first code example anyway.

EDIT: Whoops, double-checked the MSDN.  Creating the ReadOnlyCollection just wraps the underlying array as an O(1) operation. So you could do that in Mtx's constructor.  However, if you change the passed-in array outside the class, its alterations will be reflected in the resulting ReadOnlyCollection.  Perhaps this can be used to your advantage with what your specific needs are.